# Plotting `Minimize` outcome yields an empty graph

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

Why doesn't the following simple plotting of `Minimize` result work?

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[a_] := Minimize[(x - a)^2, x][[2]]
Plot[f[a], {a, 0, 10}]
```

The output is just an empty graph as follows:

[image]

I also tried `NMinimize` but the outcome is the same.

Comment: I am not clear what is it you are trying to plot. Is this what you meant? `f[a_]:=Minimize[(x-a)^2,x][[2]][[1,2]];
data=Table[f[a],{a,0,10}];
ListLinePlot[data,Mesh->All,MeshStyle->Red]` screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SiCF.png)  your original code was generating a `Rule` and not a function as you expect.

Comment: @Nasser, exactly, thank you! May I ask: Why [[2]][[1,2]] instead of just [[2]] when I would like to access the second result of `Minimize` which is the optimal $x$?

Comment: This was just one way to access the value. There are many other way to do it. The way you had it, if you type `f[1]` it was returning back `{x->1}`  so you wanted the `1` here, right? So given   `z={x->1}`  how would you get the `1` out? it is `z[[1,2]]` and that is what I used. again, there are probably better ways to do this. may be using pattern.

Comment: Since you just want the argument that minimizes the function for a given `a`, I think it makes a lot more sense to use `ArgMin` here:
$$ $$
`f[a_] := ArgMin[(x - a)^2, x]`

Comment: @Nasser, it seems your method yields discrete values by using `Table`. Can we make it continuous?

Comment: @Nasser, one more question: In my original code, I defined a function `f[a_]` and used it in `Plot`. So I'm confused in what way this is just generating a rule not a function?

Comment: Or `f[a_] := x /. Minimize[(x - a)^2, x][[2]]
Plot[f[a], {a, 0, 10}]`

Comment: Minimize returns a value and a rule. To convert the rule to its argument use: `x /. rule`